# What was the weather like in Pangaea's equatorial regions ( i.e. 23 latitude North to 23 latitude South )?

Tags: meteorology, climate

I've been having this burning question about the tropical climate of Pangaea but not sure how to ask until now.

So far I've read that the carbon dioxide levels back then were much higher than it is now ( about [2000 - 4000 ppm](https://eos.org/articles/a-dip-in-atmospheric-carbon-may-have-facilitated-dinosaur-dispersal) ) and the fact that coastal regions around the Tethys ocean were constantly affected by super hurricanes and extreme monsoons ( due to the warm currents coming from Panthalassa ocean and the contiguous landmass of Pangaea ).

Would it be hotter and more humid than today's tropical regions ? Or would the region experience extreme changes in temperature and humidity throughout the day ?